# SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self) where to add it?

Tags: ios, swift2, in-app-purchase

here is simple question, where to add `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)` in `viewDidLoad` or in some func like restore or buy button? As I see you can add both but whats best practise ti put it?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

As described in below link as best practices for implementing In App Purchase, you should "Add a transaction queue observer at application launch".

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2387/_index.html